# error (unused argument) using plyr with lattice xyplot

Tags: r, plyr, lattice

Hello everybody on stackoverflow,

it's my first question asked here... (well, actually the first one no one had already replied to!).

I'm trying to use lattice xyplot function to plot a big df (2362422 rows), that should be splitted by a variable in several subplots (each of them with about 52 panels).

This is a highly simplified reproduction of the df and of the code I'm using:

```
library(lattice)
library(plyr)
set.seed(1)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(x = rnorm(30), y=(1:2), z=rnorm(30), q = c("a","b","c","d","e")))
grpro <- function () {xyplot (x ~ z| q, data=df)}
grpro()
```

When I try to call the grpro function with d_ply to plot all the subplots based on the y variable, with the following code

```
d_ply(df, .(y), grpro)
```

I get the following error

```
Error in .fun(.data[[i]], ...) : unused argument (.data[[i]])
```

For what I understand, d_ply function splits the df in several dataframes, in this case two dfs based on the values "1" and "2" of y.
I assume that my code is working on that, and any other argument used in my grpro seems to be useful also when I split the df by y.
So, where am I wrong?

Thanks a lot for your help,
MZ

Comment: Your `grpro` function doesn't accept any arguments. Your function should have a parameter where `d_ply` can pass the subset of data for a particular group. And with lattice, you're not going to want to ignore the result because calling `xyplot()` doesn't actually draw the plot. It builds an object representing the plot. You'll need to explicitly `print() that object in your function if you want to draw the plot.

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks, now I got the reason for the error... for the .print, yes, i omitted that part but it was in my original code, I was pretty sure that it wasn't causing any harm to the rest of the code.

At the moment, I'm still figuring out how to write the `grpro` function in a way that can easily work with `plyr` functions

Comment: @MrFlick ok, I got it. It was as easy as 1, 2, 3... All I really need is to write it like this: `grpro <- function () {xyplot (x ~ z| q, data=df)` (plus obviously the `.print=T` call!)